# DC-DC Converter - Why is the input voltage called Vg?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, boost, terminology, buck-boost

In the textbook I'm reading (Fundamentals of Power Electronics 2nd Ed, Erickson and Maksimovic), the input voltage for several different types of converter circuits is labeled Vg. The textbook gives no explanation for what the g refers to. Does anyone know?

[image: Example circuit]

Comment: I guarantee most of us have not read this particular text book. As, i'm sure you're aware, unit subscripts tend to be descriptive. E.G. Vgs tends to mean Voltage between Gate and Source. Seeing a typical schematic may help us decypher this with you.

Comment: the author of the book probably knows,  if you want us to guess post a few photos of the diagrams,

Comment: 'g' for 'generator'?

Comment: Yes, Vg for generator voltage was used long before FET's appeared.

Comment: Sometimes you see a synonym of \$V_s\$ for a voltage source, instead of \$V_g\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltage generator, maybe? I used this text in school and they use the Vg nomenclature from the get-go. I don't think there's anything special about it.

On page 3, they introduced Vg for the first time:

[image]

So Vg is just the way they call the input voltage to the converters in the text.